# How can I consolidate Event-Based Rows in a SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple SQL Table with the following Fields:

- Event Start (datetime)
- Event End (datetime)
- Event Description (varchar)

The data inside represents a continuous timeline broken in different types of events. Every [Event End] will match an [Event Start] field (like a chain).

My challenge here, is that some of the events are the same, see below for example:

```
Event Start        Event End          Event Description
1/1/2018 07:00:00  1/1/2018 07:30:00  Breakfast
1/1/2018 07:30:00  1/1/2018 07:40:00  Drive To Work
1/1/2018 07:40:00  1/1/2018 07:55:00  Drive To Work
1/1/2018 07:55:00  1/1/2018 12:00:00  Working
```

But I would like a SQL Query that can display a view as follows:

```
Event Start        Event End          Event Description
1/1/2018 07:00:00  1/1/2018 07:30:00  Breakfast
1/1/2018 07:30:00  1/1/2018 07:55:00  Drive To Work
1/1/2018 07:55:00  1/1/2018 12:00:00  Working
```

In my table I can have more than 2 events that need to be merged into a single row, in case you are wondering if we can only do a simple JOIN and fix the issue, probably recursive methods need to be applied but I do not know how. do you know how can the SQL query can be build?

Comment: Do you really have spaces in your column names?

Comment: No really, for sake of simplicity, the example above discarts the real field names and other fields not relevant for this challenge. You can provide a query with other field names if desired.

Comment: It is often easier to deal with the real tablename and columns names. If the problem is more complex than seen above, then your example may be over simplified.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
select
      "Event Description"
    , min("Event Start") as "Event Start"
    , max("Event End") as "Event End"
from that_table
group by
      "Event Description"
```

**BUT** relying on just a description is likely to be a substantial issue, for example misspellings or just accidental multiple spaces may cause differences your didn't expect - or repeated descriptions may see tasks "joined" that should not be joined.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal; I agree about the substantial issue with the description, and in the real table I have a category id that solves that issue. As I stated before, I just wanted to provide context on what I am looking for. The query you proposed does not consider the fact I can have different type of events in the middle. Your proposal will group all drive to work events regardless if there is an event that separates them. The rule is to consolidate only continuous events.

Comment: If there is more detail available in the table - use that detail. One can only offer assistance with the facts as presented....

Comment: *Your proposal will group all drive to work events regardless if there is an event that separates them. The rule is to consolidate only continuous events.* Define "continuous" please. **IF** you trying to imply that there is the order of rows that is important, then: **What column(s) in the table produce that required order?** (i.e. more detail of your table is needed)

Comment: The event start and event end columns are critical for this question. The table must be sorted by event start to see the table in cronological order. The objective is to group duplicate events of the same type that happened right after the other. If I use the group by expression all events will be grouped regardless they happened after or before a different event.

Comment: Search for "gaps and islands".  Your latest comment suggesrs you are looking for "islands". But your sample data might not be adequate to explain your real problem.